# Running GLSL Compute shader without a graphic context

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I'd like to write a GLSL compute shader that works like an OpenCL application. I'm a newbie in GPGPU so i don't even know if it is possible.

The problem is that i'd like to run that program without needing a graphic server, like X11 on Unix. Is there a way i can initialize a dummy glContext to run that program in any terminal, without needs of graphic environment?

The host application is written in C++, if it matters anything.

Comment: All those implementations seem to need an X11 server running in background, and there's none in tty... are there any working examples?

Comment: This is hard to understand: *Why is a question that specifically asks whether there is the possibility to do this without a graphic server, a duplicate to two questions that don't have this specific part? And have only answers that exactly require, e.g. X11? So not even the answers fit the question.*